# How do I add a node to multiple shaders?

Tags: materials, shader-nodes

[image]
I need help copying a node between the main shader and the material output for a shader automatically, to essentially hundreds of textures at once.
Imagine a scene that has already been textured/materialed and add this node between the shader and output. The node setup has been grouped so it's easy to copy and paste manually, but that is cumbersome.
[image]

[image]
[image]